# Mustache.js Object #<Document> has no method 'search'

Tags: javascript, template-engine, mustache

I am using mustache.js as my client-side templating solution, but I was caught in a problem that I do not have any idea why is this happening:

first of, here is my template :

```
<ul>
    {{#steps}}
    <li>
        <a href="{{url}}">
            <div class="step_visual {{step_status}}">
                <span class="step_description">{{description}}</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    {{/steps}}
</ul>
```

and here is the json object I am trying to passed in :

```
var view = {
    "steps": [
        {
            "url": "complete_profile",
            "step_status": "done",
            "description": "Complete Proflie"
        },
        {
            "url": "complete_form1",
            "step_status": "active",
            "description": "Submission of Form 1"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I tried running this script to render it out in in my app

```
var content = Mustache.render(template, view);
$(target).html(content).hide().fadeIn();
```

where `template` = the template above | 
`view` = the view object
and `target` is the html element I wish to change the content

The thing that cofuses me is that it works well when my template looks like

```
{{#steps}}
    {{url}}
    {{description}}
    {{step_status}}
{{/steps}}
```

or if my template does not have anything to loop on.

what could be the bug? do you think it is a mustache bug?

**EDIT**
As I have seen the code works,

Could it be a problem in the manner I called the function?

```
tmplReplaceContent : function(json, tmpl, target) {
    var regex = new RegExp("\{{[a-zA-Z\.\_]*\}}"),
    view = '';
    function setOutput(template) {
        var content = Mustache.render(template, view);
        $(target).html(content).hide().fadeIn();
    }
    function doJSON(json) {
        view = json;
        if(!regex.test(tmpl)){
            /* get mustache tmpl from the path */
            $.get(msi.vars.tmpl_url + tmpl + '.mustache', setOutput);
        } else {
            setOutput(tmpl);
        }
    }
    /* json -> check if object */
    if (typeof json === 'object') {
        doJSON(json);
    } else {
        /* getJSON from the path */
        $.getJSON(msi.vars.base_url + json, doJSON);
    }
}
```

Comment: You code works, your error is somewhere else. http://jsfiddle.net/KzEEV/

Comment: Yeah, I think so too, I tested it here too  : http://mustache.github.com/#demo  . . I updated the question, added some code that might be the source of the bug.

Comment: I would implement the `tmplReplaceContent` function differently but it does not look too suspicious to me. It's probably a good idea to debug this with Chrome. Set it to "pause on uncaught exceptions" and inspect the call tree and scope variables to find out what's going on.

Comment: I tried it, but I don't know how should I check it, I found an exception on scope vars, local,that looks like `arguments: Array[2]
0: "search"
1: #document
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
get message: function () { [native code] }
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set message: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
type: "undefined_method"
__proto__: Error`

Comment: after doing several testings, I found out it's something about the mustache engine, it throws an error when the template file is coming from an external file. I can't find a remedy on this, I am thinking of saving the content of the external file to a variable, then use it. But I don't know how.

Comment: Can you tell me the line in the original, uncompressed Mustache source where the error occurs?

Comment: line 106 : `var match, pos = this.tail.search(re);`

I think it is a problem in my implementation, because I tried the same implementation in handlebar.js, and it gives me the save error `Mustache.js Object #<Document> has no method 'match'`

I think I should think of another way of getting the template from other location

Comment: I see... `tail` ought to be a string. I have actually no idea where the `search()` method they use comes from. Very strange.

Comment: but take note, It only happens when I fetch the template from an external file, but when I do hard code it, it works!, :D

Comment: Here's what I would do. I'd set a break point on that line and inspect the variables `tail` and `re` when it hits. Then I'd try to anticipate  what number `search` was supposed to return, add a dummy `search()` method to `tail` that does just that and find out if that's already enough to make it run. The line definitely looks fishy to me.

Comment: can't find what's really wrong, I'm no expert on inspecting and deducing what is wrong, I'll just rewrite the code, or use dust.js

Comment: Too bad that I could not help you further.

Comment: I found out something that could solve the problem, the `$.get` function returns an object instead of a string, maybe I could workaround with that now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I never felt this feeling of relief, for I have solve my question on my own, first thanks to [Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak) for continuously watched my comments and help me solve the problem.

I could have solve the problem earlier if I just continue on console.logging things, but I stopped.

One thing I noticed is that the `$.get` function gives me `#<Document>`, which is pretty much an object, I could have deduced it earlier that the response is an object, seeing from the title of my question that obviously it's returning an object.

So why not add the `dataType` attribute?

```
function doJSON(data){
    dataSource = data;
    if (!regex.test(tpl)) {
        $.get(msi.vars.tmpl_url + tpl + '.mustache', render, 'text'); // see here
    } else {
        render(tpl);
    }
}
```

And that ultimately solved the problem.

Comment: Very nice work. +1 - You could (and probably should) solve this on the server side by sending out `*.mustache` files as `Content-Type: text/plain`. This way you wouldn't need to change the `.get()` request. I've also set up an exemplary solution that makes use of jQuery's `Deferred` to solve the problem of synchronizing two asynchronous tasks (fetching the JSON and the template) here: http://pastebin.com/hrFYGk5T. My first suspicion was that you'd have a timing issue, but it became clear soon that that was not the case. Maybe you can make use of it/learn something new.

Comment: oh wow!! you really gave some effort, thanks for that!!! super!! I barely understand the code you gave me, maybe bec. I don't know it, yet. I'll bookmark that and try it too, so I can understand. Thanks!!

Comment: @Salac The `Deferred` concept is very useful and not too difficult, either. If you don't use it for this project, you definitely will find it helpful another time.